# Real Time Database querying using while loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop

I'm currently developing a user interface for a Raspberry Pi and Arduino based Scalextric telemetry system. The system uses a series of light sensors around the track, the output of these sensors are inserted into a mySQL database.

From this data i need to display race statistics. For example if a car passes over the light sensor at the start of the track, the current lap is incremented by one. I've written the following code for this:

```
    <?
$currentLap = 1;
$checkpointTime = '';
$checkpointNumber = '';
$checkdb = $db -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM laps WHERE `race_id` = :raceID");
$checkdb -> bindParam (':raceID', $raceID);

while ($currentLap <= $totallaps) {

    $checkdb -> execute();
    while ($row = $checkdb -> fetch()) {

        $checkpointTime = $row['checkpoint_time'];
        $checkpointNumber = $row['checkpoint_number'];
    }

switch($checkpointNumber) {
      case 1: 
      $currentLap = $currentLap + 1;
      break;

      case 2:
      //Lane 2
      $currentLap = $currentLap + 1;
      break;
    }

}

?>
```

I then display the current lap with:

```
<? echo $currentLap; ?>
```

However when i visit the page that contains this code, nothing is displayed and the page seems to load continuously.

Is a while loop the correct way to display the data as it occurs or is there another method is should be using?

Comment: Where are you defining `$raceID`? Also, since you don't have a default in your `switch($checkpointNumber)`, than if `while ($row = $checkdb -> fetch())` does not return any rows, than `$checkpointNumber` will never match `1`|`2`, so `$currentLap` is never increases, so you will have an unending loop.

Comment: @Sean Race ID was defined in a file called "raceStats.php". I've included this file at the top of the page. 

I'm not sure what i could use for a default in my switch statement as the checkpoint number can only be one or two. The query should always be returning values as the car goes round the track.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a while loop the correct way to display the data as it occurs or is
>   there another method is should be using?

Yes but you should not be running execute in a loop, there is no point in doing so, change your code to

```
$checkdb = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM laps WHERE `race_id` = :raceID");
$checkdb ->bindParam(':raceID', $raceID);
$checkdb -> execute();
while ($row = $checkdb -> fetch()) {
    $checkpointTime = $row['checkpoint_time'];
    $checkpointNumber = $row['checkpoint_number'];
}
```